# Аналоги Chart in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, диаграммы

Нужно вывести графики на WPF окне, не знаю каким способ реализовать.
Ищу аналог Chart из Windows Forms

Comment: Ну в конце-концов можно сектора и вручную нарисовать. [(1)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/194401/10105), [(2)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461999/10105), [(3)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/632492/10105).

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что [вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Откройте для себя WindowsFormsHost и используйте тот самый Chart.